# Error when trying to get content of a VBA MsgBox in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to intercept VB MsgBoxes from a word template and click them automatically. This code is inserted in a C# Winforms Application, in a class and `KillMbox()` runs at the click of a button from that form.
I have tried the app in Debug Mode of Visual Studio and the code ran perfectly, intercepting the VBA messagebox.

However, after I have closed the Debug Mode and tried again, I receive `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Unknown Module. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

The error appears at the line `GetWindowText(txtHandle, sb, len + 1);`.
I have tried the app at a different computer in Debug Mode and it has the same issue, working only for the first time.

In Build version, the app just crashes, receiving `App-Name has stopped working.`

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")] static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)] static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        public static void KillMbox()
        {
            for (int h = 0; h == 0;)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                h = FindWindow(null, "Microsoft Word");
                if (h != 0)
                {
                    IntPtr hAsIntPtr = new IntPtr(h); 
                    IntPtr txtHandle = FindWindowEx(hAsIntPtr, IntPtr.Zero, "Static", null);
                    int len = GetWindowTextLength(txtHandle);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    GetWindowText(txtHandle, sb, len + 1);
                    SendMessage(h, 16, 0, 0);
                    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());

                }
            }
        }
```

Is this a code-related error or a bug? Thank you!

Comment: why dont you try to execute the code when there is no msgbox in the word document. Im sure your error happens, because FindWindowEx returns null. Also read the documentation for the pInvokes you're doing, you have to handle the errors they might return, in the declaration put: SetLastError = true, and then use GetLastError() to get details about the error that might have occured

Comment: The GetWindowText() call lies about the size of the buffer.  The resulting memory corruption can cause all kinds of random weirdo errors.  Get ahead with StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len+1);  And strongly favor System.Windows.Automation for this kind of code.